# Delete memory to window handle from child on close in QT

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, delete-operator

Let see my conf:

```
mainwindow.h
second_window.h
```

1. Keep pointer to `second_window` in class methods ( `public: second_window * h_window;` )
2. Class `mainwindow` opens `second_window`.

In `second_window` i catch `eventClose();`
And there i want to `delete h_window;`
But i got a access error, i thought that window is still opened so when i try to delete pointer memory i got error.

Other idea when i should delete this pointer?

Comment: Please post sample code that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both windows are independant and thus having no parents, then a way to solve is with QPointer and setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose).

```
class mainwindow : public QWidget {
  public:
    ~mainwindow() {
      delete h_window; // deletes h_window if it is not 0 (that is, not closed yet)
    }
    void showSecondWindow() {
      if ( ! h_window ) {
        h_window = new second_window();
      }
      h_window->show();
      h_window->activateWindow();
    }
  private:
    QPointer<second_window> h_window; // h_window will automatically become 0 when second_window is deleted.
}

class second_window : public QWidget {
  public:
    second_window() {
      setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose); // automatically delete itself when window is closed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to delete the object of the `second_window` if you set a parent for it:

```
h_window = new second_window(this); // in the constructor of mainwindow
```

When an object is deleted and it has children, the destructor automatically deletes each child. So the child objects get deleted automatically when the parent is deleted.

It is recommended to create child objects on the heap and parent them immediately. If you don't parent immediately, you can explicitly parent using the `setParent()` function.

If for some reason you don't want your object to have a parent, you can also use a `QSharedPointer` to manage the lifetime of the object.

Comment: Don't forget about setting the `Qt::Window` flag on the child widget, otherwise it will become a child widget, not a top-level window.

Comment: @KubaOber, Never knew Qt::Window can "extract" itself from parent QWidget :) But after testing on MS Windows with a parented second_window, I found problems: 1. second_window will always be in front of mainwindow even when mainwindow has focus. 2. second_window is not shown on Windows taskbar. Though this can be solved by SetWindowLong with WS_EX_APPWINDOW, there are other problems: a) second_window does not appear in Alt+Tab window list. b) Minimizing mainwindow will make  second_window disappear from taskbar. c) Clicking mainwindow or second_window on taskbar brings them to front together.

Comment: Alt+Tab is for switching applications, not windows, I thought. Both of those windows belong to the same application, so the behavior you describe is I think correct. It's as if you had a dialog box.

Comment: @KubaOber, IMHO, Alt+Tab is for switching windows appearing on taskbar. For instance, all Windows Explorer windows appears in Alt+Tab window list, but there is only one explorer.exe running.

Comment: @fxam OK, obviously I don't use Windows all that much. Sorry for the confusion.